# gsub return an empty string when no match is found

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm using the `gsub` function in R to return occurrences of my pattern (reference numbers) on a list of text.  This works great unless no match is found, in which case I get the entire string back, instead of an empty string.  Consider the example:

```
data <- list("a sentence with citation (Ref. 12)",
             "another sentence without reference")

sapply(data, function(x) gsub(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1", x))
```

Returns:

```
[1] "Ref. 12"                            "another sentence without reference"
```

But I'd like to get

```
[1] "Ref. 12"                            ""
```

Thanks!

Comment: `gsub` cannot (currently, 2.15.0) do this because: "If `replacement` contains backreferences which are not defined in `pattern` the result is undefined (but most often the backreference is taken to be `""`)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably go a different route, since the `sapply` doesn't seem necessary to me as these functions are vectorized already:

```
fun <- function(x){
    ind <- grep(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*",x,value = FALSE)
    x <- gsub(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1", x)
    x[-ind] <- ""
    x
}

fun(data)
```

Comment: any reason to use `grep` and not `grepl`?

Comment: @David I don't think so, it's just what my fingers happened to type first.

Answer (score 7):

according to the documentation, this is a feature of `gsub` it returns the input string if there are no matches to the supplied pattern matches returns the entire string.

here, I use the function `grepl` first to return a logical vector of the presence/absence of the pattern in the given string:

```
ifelse(grepl(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", data), 
      gsub(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1", data), 
      "")
```

embedding this in a function:

```
mygsub <- function(x){
     ans <- ifelse(grepl(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", x), 
              gsub(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1", x), 
              "")
     return(ans)
}

mygsub(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
xs <- sapply(data, function(x) gsub(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1", x))
xs[xs==data] <- ""
xs
#[1] "Ref. 12" ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `strapplyc` in the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)

L <- fn$sapply(unlist(data), ~ strapplyc(x, "Ref. \\d+"))
unlist(fn$sapply(L, ~ ifelse(length(x), x, "")))
```

which gives this:

```
a sentence with citation (Ref. 12) another sentence without reference 
                         "Ref. 12"                                 ""
```

If you don't mind list output then you could just use L and forget about the last line of code.  Note that the `fn$` prefix turns the formula arguments of the function its applied to into function calls so the first line of code could be written without `fn` as  `sapply(unlist(data), function(x) strapplyc(x, "Ref x. \\d+"))` .

Comment: I've never seen `fn$` used - where did you find that?

Comment: In the gsubfn package, see `?fn` and section 7 of the `gsubfn` vignette.

Answer (score 0):

You might try embedding `grep( ..., value = T)` in that function.

```
data <- list("a sentence with citation (Ref. 12)",
         "another sentence without reference")

unlist( sapply(data, function(x) { 
  x <- gsub(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1", x)
  grep( "Ref\\.", x, value = T )
  } ) )
```

Kind of bulky but it works? It also removes the empty 2nd reference.

Comment: Works for me.  In my case I'll drop the unlist, since I still want to know where the missing data is.  Thanks!

Comment: @cboettig Note that the `sapply` is overkill here.

Comment: @joran thanks, I was simplifying the example from a case that I think needed the sapply because data a list of lists, forgot I didn't need it here. ;-) That is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

**based on @joran 's answer**

## function:

```
extract_matches <- function(x,pattern,replacement,replacement_nomatch=""){
    x <- gsub(pattern,replacement,x)
    x[-grep(pattern,x,value = FALSE)] <- replacement_nomatch
    x
}
```

## usage:

```
data <- list("with citation (Ref. 12)", "without reference", "")
extract_matches(data,  ".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to use gsub but specify you want '' in a new function

```
noFalsePositives <- function(a,b,x) {
  return(ifelse(gsub(a,b,x)==x,'',gsub(a,b,x)))
}
# usage
noFalsePositives(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*", "\\1", data)
# [1] "Ref. 12" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out and I did not see it listed.

```
  data <- list("a sentence with citation (Ref. 12)",
               "another sentence without reference")
  gsub(".*(Ref. (\\d+)).*|.*()", "\\1", data)
```